# Selecting data from one table while storing (inserting) in two?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to copy data to a new database. However another table is included in the process where data should be put.

Old table:

> `DB1`.`dbo`.`pages` (id, title, content)

New table(s):

> `DB2`.`dbo`.`Page` (id)
>   `DB2`.`dbo`.`Content` (id, pageid, title, content)

How can I select all data from `pages` while splitting/storing it in `Page` **and** `Content`?

Comment: Why is it important to execute SELECT and INSERT in one query? Did you consider using transactions?

Comment: Just curious... Why would you have a table with only an id?

Comment: Two queries is also possible :), sorry if it wasn't clear. It's a one time operation...

Comment: There are more fields, however not needed to illustrate the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is pageid? is that the id from Page?

If so and this assumes id in the Content table is an identity

```
insert into DB2.dbo.Page (id)
select id from DB1.dbo.pages

insert into DB2.dbo.Content(pageid, title, content)
select id, title, content from DB1.dbo.pages
```

Still a little puzzled by this design

Comment: Thanks, this is actually a good solution to my problem! To unpuzzle: multiple language pages...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to [chain two inserts](http://rusanu.com/2008/04/09/chained-updates/) by using the OUTPUT clause:

setup:

```
create table Page (id int )
create table Content (id int , pageid int, title varchar(100), content varchar(max))

create table pages (id int, title varchar(100), content varchar(max))

insert into pages values (1, 'Lorem', 'Ipsum');
insert into pages values (2, 'eum', 'aliquam vivendo placerat ad');
```

Actual insert:

```
insert into Content (id, pageid, title, content)
output inserted.pageid into Page(id)
select id, id, title, content from pages;
```

Proof:

```
select * from Page;
select * from Content;
```

This can be actually usefull because the two inserts are inside a single statement so they are automatically contained in an implicit transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible directly. If your select is expensive, you may consider inserting it into a temporary table and then inserting into the final tables inside a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Cant u do it with two separate requests? Do it like:

Insert into db2.dbo.page
      Select id from db1.dbo.pages

And:

Insert into db2.dbo.content (id_page,title,content)
       Select id,title,content from db1.dbo.pages

I guess this should work.